# C programming exit not working

Tags: c

I have a problem exiting my program. I just want the program to exit when I enter 5, but this error pops up:

> Process returned 0 (0x0) execution time : 3.179 s Press any key to
>   continue.

Screenshot:
[image]

What can be the problem??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define p printf
#define s scanf

int main()
{
char ans='y', asc_desc;
signed char name[100];
int a, b, c, prog_num, num;
double product=1;
float ave, sum, count;

p("Please enter your name: ");
s(" %[^\n]s", &name);
system("cls");

do
{
p("%s, welcome to Menu Program\n", name);
p("\n1. Ascending/Descending\n\n2. Sum/Average\n\n3. Factorial\n\n4. Display the first 10 positive integers from the number entered.\n\n5. Exit");
p("\n\nPlease select the number of program: ");
s("%d", &prog_num);
system("cls");

if(prog_num==1)
{
    do
    {
        p("\t\t\t  *Ascending or Descending?*");
        p("\n\nPlease enter any three integers:\n\n");
        s("%d", &a);
        p("\n");
        s("%d", &b);
        p("\n");
        s("%d", &c);
        p("\n");
        p("Do you want your integers sorted ascending or descending? a/d\n\n");
        s(" %c", &asc_desc);
        if(asc_desc=='a'||asc_desc=='A')
        {
            if(c>b&&b>a)
                p("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, b, c);
            else if(c<b&&b<a)
                p("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", c, b, a);
            else if(a<c&&c<b)
                p("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, c, b);
            else if(b<c&&c<a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, c, a);
            else if(c<a&&a<b)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", c, a, b);
            else if(b<a&&a<c)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, a, c);
            else if(c==b&&b>a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, b, c);
            else if(c==b&&b<a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", c, b, a);
            else if(a==c&&c<b)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, c, b);
            else if(b==c&&c<a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, c, a);
            else if(c==a&&a<b)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", c, a, b);
            else if(b==a&&a<c)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, a, c);
            else if(b==c&&c<a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, c, a);
            else if(a==b&&b>a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, c, a);
            else if(a==c&&c>b)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, c, a);
            else if(a==b&&b>c)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", c, a, b);
            else if(a==b&&b==c)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, a, a);
            else printf("\nInvalid input!");
        }
        else if(asc_desc=='d'||asc_desc=='D')
        {
            if(c>b&&b>a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", c, b, a);
            else if(c<b&&b<a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, b, c);
            else if(a<c&&c<b)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, c, a);
            else if(b<c&&c<a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, c, b);
            else if(c<a&&a<b)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, a, c);
            else if(b<a&&a<c)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", c, a, b);
            else if(c==b&&b>a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", c, b, a);
            else if(c==b&&b<a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, b, c);
            else if(a==c&&c<b)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, c, a);
            else if(b==c&&c<a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, c, b);
            else if(c==a&&a<b)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, a, c);
            else if(b==a&&a<c)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", c, a, b);
            else if(b==c&&c<a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, c, b);
            else if(a==b&&b>a)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, c, b);
            else if(a==c&&c>b)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, c, b);
            else if(a==b&&b>c)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", b, a, c);
            else if(a==b&&b==c)
                printf("\nArranged numbers are: %d %d %d", a, a, a);
            else printf("\nInvalid input!");
        }
        else printf("\nInvalid input!");
        printf("\n\nDo you want to try again? y/n\n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ans);
        system("cls");
    }
    while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y');
}
else if(prog_num==2)
{
    do
    {
        printf("Enter any numbers. I will stop only if you enter zero.\n");
        num=1;
        ave=0;
        count=0;
        sum=0;
        for(;num!=0;)
        {
            printf("\n");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            count++;
            sum=num+sum;
        }
        count--;
        ave=sum/count;
        printf("\nThe sum and average of the integers are: %0.2f and %0.2f respectively.", sum, ave);
        p("\n\nDo you want to try again? y/n\n\n");
        s(" %c", &ans);
        system("cls");
    }
    while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y');
}
else if(prog_num==3)
{
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &a);
        p("\n");
        for (b = 1; b<=a; b++)
        {
        product=product*b;
        if (b!=a)
        {

            printf("%d x ", b);
        }
        else
            printf("%d", b);
        }
printf("\n\nThe factorial of %d is %.0f", a, product);
printf("\n\nDo you want to try again? y/n\n\n");
scanf(" %s", &ans);
product=1;
system("cls");
}
while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y');
}
else if(prog_num==4)
{
    do
    {
        p("\t\t\t *First 10 Positive Integers*\n\n");
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &a);
        p("\n\nThe first 10 positive integer from %d is: \n\n", a);
        if(a>=0)
        {
           for (b = 1; b<=10; b++)
           {
                printf("%d ",a++);
           }
        }

        else if(a<0)
            p("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10");
        printf("\n\nTry Again?(y/n):\t");
        scanf(" %s", &ans);
        system("cls");
    }
        while(ans=='y');
}
else if(prog_num=5)
{

}
}
while(ans=='n'||ans=='N');
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Please don't use `p` and `s` as function names. `printf()` is verbose and preferred.

Comment: `prog_num=5` should be `prog_num==5`,

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: Please strip down your code to a [mcve]. Focus on the **`M`**.

Comment: Please indent your code if you expect others to read it.

Comment: `scanf(" %s", &ans);` --> `scanf(" %c", &ans);`, `s(" %[^\n]s", &name);` --> `s(" %[^\n]", name);`

Comment: Please.  Apart of using p and s (not recommended in a comment before) what you have to do is not to mesh both (p and printf).  Please be coherent, indent your code and comment as appropiate to be readable by others.

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not an error the program is exiting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, next time present us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as @Olaf mentioned.

Your code is so long and hard to read, but replace yours

```
else if(prog_num=5)
{

}
```

with

```
else if(prog_num==5)
{
  printf("prog_num is 5, program will exit now.\n");
  break; // exit from the loop
}
```

and add `return 0;` at the end of your program (just before last `}` brace). In addition to that, text you may see in console is not an error, it means your program has been finished w/o any problems.

You should definitely read about [switch statement in C/C++](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm).